# Set device orientation as landscape for iPad only

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, device-orientation

I want landscape left and landscape right to be allowed on the iPad only, and not on the iPhone. How should I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your info.plist file to have entries that look something like this:

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
```

More information about those keys can be seen [in this Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-SW5) and I worked up the answer by looking at this [public repo's info.plist file](https://github.com/soffes/universal-ipad-iphone-example/blob/master/Shared/Universal-Info.plist) (though it's from iOS 3.2, I did try it out on sample project and it seems to still work fine).